Mysterious "Killed" message
I am trying to run a program that consumes a large, but not infeasible amount of memory (see below). I checked that my computer has 15.6GiB according to htop. However, this exits with the message Killed. Why is this happening and how can I confirm it?
import datetime
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1_000_000_000)
start = datetime.datetime.now()
(x + x).sum()
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)


Does this answer your question? What killed my process and why?

Your code needs at least 8 GB to store x, and at least that much again to store x + x long enough to compute its sum.

If you want to optimize memory usage, np.add(x, x, out=x).sum() rather than (x + x).sum() should help.
